# Dividing negative numbers in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to divide a positive number with a negative one. I have the code for 2 positive numbers. Can anyone tell me what should I change to divide 25 with -5 for example ? Thank you in advance!

This is the division code:
https://pastebin.com/QjGG0RsX

```
module division(divisor, dividend, remainder, result);
     
    input [7:0] divisor, dividend;
    output reg [7:0] result, remainder;
     
    // Variables
    integer i;
    reg [7:0] divisor_copy, dividend_copy;
    reg [7:0] temp;
```

and test bench:

https://pastebin.com/h3zg1mTV

```
module stimulus_division;
 
    // Inputs
    reg [7:0] divisor;
    reg [7:0] dividend;
 
    // Outputs
    wire [7:0] remainder;
    wire [7:0] result;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remember dividend and divisor sign. If most significant bit is equal to 1 then your number is negative otherwise your number is positive. For example:

```systemverilog
assign divisor_sign = divisor[7];
```

2. Get absolute value of dividend and divisor . For example:

```systemverilog
assign fdivisor = divisor_sign ? -divisor : divisor;
```

3. Make unsigned division.
4. If dividend and divisor have different signs then change your result to negative number. For example:

```systemverilog
assign sresult = (reg_divisor_sign ^ reg_dividend_sign) ? -result : result;
```

If your divisor is negative then change your remainder to negative number. For example:

```systemverilog
assign sremainder = reg_divisor_sign ? -remainder : remainder;
```

You should remember that your division take few cycles, thats mean you have to remember dividend and divisor sign at the beggining and hold it for whole unsigned division.